# Methods to preserve autographs on an acoustic guitar

Tags: acoustic-guitar, instruments, maintenance

Some months ago I met my favourite band backstage and got my guitar signed by the band members. Since then I avoid playing this specific guitar to not blur or completely erase the autographs. I decided that this guitar will serve as decoration object in my living room.

The band members used an ordinary paint pen (brand: edding, black, water resistant) and signed the front side. The guitar is a [Fender Squier SA-105CE NA](https://www.thomann.de/at/fender_squier_sa105ce_na.htm). It has a **laminated spruce top**.

Now I am wondering what I can do to preserve these autographs as long as possible. Is it enough to just not play it anymore? Are there further steps necessary in order to keep the signatures on the guitar for a long time?

This question is related to the guitar instrument, but not directly to music theory or practicing. Since I think some of you might as well have signed guitars I thought I might ask here for tips. Sorry though if it is too off-topic.

Comment: Overcoat, of course.  Whether this will significantly change the guitar's sound is no doubt a flame-war topic.    Anyway, from a cellist's point of view,  guitars are dirt-cheap, so keep this one on the wall and buy another :-)

Comment: It's already on the wall and I bought another. I do not intend to seriously play it anymore so the sound doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 2):

The signatures will most likely stay there anyway, if the guitar isn't in direct sunlight, which it shouldn't be anyway. Assuming the finish is cellulose - it may or may not be - a flash over with celly lacquer would preserve them better, but I wouldn't do that without consulting the fender Squier factory first.

Comment: You have to watch out for the solvent in spray lacquer dissolving the  ink used for the signature.  Some markers are susceptible to solvent / alcohol and will run and smear while the top coat dries.  Archival clear plastic adhesive sheeting (like the kind used to laminate old photos) may be a better option.